# What conclusions can I derive from this family of trace inequalities?

Tags: matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis, gaussian, traces

**Problem.** Let $n_1,\ldots,n_s,m_1,\ldots,m_s\ge 0$ be nonnegative integers and set $m := \sum_{i=1}^s m_i$ and $n := \sum_{i=1}^s n_i$. Let $\oplus$ be an operation on matrices which stacks them in a block diagonal way, i.e., $B \oplus C = \begin{bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & C\end{bmatrix}$.

Suppose $H \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric matrices. Assume that

$$
\operatorname{tr}\left((\oplus_{i=1}^s A_i)^\top H (\oplus_{i=1}^s A_i)\Sigma\right) \ge 0 \quad \text{for every } A_1\in \mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times n_1},\ldots,A_s \in \mathbb{R}^{m_s\times n_s}. \tag{1}
$$

*What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $H$ and $\Sigma$ for this condition to hold?*

**Context.** I've been looking into the Gaussian Jensen inequality, described in the [following blog post](https://extremal010101.wordpress.com/2021/01/01/jensens-inequality/) of Paata Ivanishvili, and I've been trying to derive the multidimensional generalization of it. The correct hypothesis for this multidimensional inequality appears exactly to be equivalent to finding a nice characterization of (1).

**Case $m_i = n_i \equiv 1$.** The univariate case is covered in the blog post. In this case, the $A_i$'s are scalars $a_i$ and $\oplus_i A_i$ is just $\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_s)$. In this case, we have

$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_s) H \operatorname{diag}\Sigma\right) = \sum_{i,j=1}^s a_i H_{ij} a_j \Sigma_{ij} = a^\top (H\circ \Sigma) a \ge 0 \text{ for all }a_1,\ldots,a_s
$$

if and only if $H\circ \Sigma$ is positive semidefinite. Here, $\circ$ is the entrywise product. I have tried generalizing this argument to $n_i,m_i > 1$ but the loss of commutativity of the block entries of $H,\Sigma$ with the $A_i$ has stymied my progress.

Comment: $H$ and $\Sigma$ each being positive semidefinite is sufficient, regardless of $n_i$, $m_i$ and $s$. Your argument shows that $H \circ \Sigma$ being positive semidefinite is necessary, regardless of $n_i$, $m_i$ and $s$. So the answer is always between these two cases.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston I believe that my argument only applies when $n_i=m_i\equiv 1$. Indeed, if $n_i\ne m_i$, $H$ and $\Sigma$ may be different sizes and $H\circ \Sigma$ may not be defined! $H$ being positive semidefinite is also not necessary: if $\Sigma$ has zeros in row $i$, then the conclusion can still hold if $H_{ii}<0.$

Comment: Yes, positive definiteness of $H$ and $\Sigma$ is only sufficient, not necessary (they could both be negative definite, for example). Your argument works just fine regardless of $n_i$ etc, as long as you suitably pad $H$ and $\Sigma$ with zeros when constructing $H \circ \Sigma$. To see this, just notice that, regardless of $n_i$ the set of matrices $\oplus_i A_i$ contain the diagonal matrices as a subset, so you can apply your argument (modulo some zero-padding stuff that I don't quite want to fiddle with).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Ah my bad. I appreciate the corrections. Thank you very much